# How to suppress php output in one-line chained terminal command

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, stdout, null

I use the following `&&`-chained one-line command in Linux terminal (Ubuntu desktop):

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/detailed_payouts && for FILE in *; do dos2unix $FILE; done && php /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydeal-join-columns-2.php && cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/xero-bills && csvstack * > xero-bills-csvstacked.csv && cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/xero-invoices && csvstack * > xero-inv-csvstacked.csv
```

However, I don't actually want to see the messy output of php  in terminal.

I've tried various approaches, such as

`nohup php filename.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

As given in this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989340/9095603

However, it totally breaks the one-liner and causes the command to exit prematurely.

I am not invested in the above approach at all - I just need any simple approach which will allow me to run the one-liner and suppress the terminal output of the php execution.

Comment: The linked question is how to run PHP as a background process and suppress the output. If you just want to achieve the latter, do you need more than just `>/dev/null`?

Comment: @DonHolgo I'm not sure what you mean, could you please explain?

Comment: The other question is not just "how do I suppress the output", but "how do I run the script in the background and suppress the output". If all you want is no output, you don't need to copy the entire command, but the `>/dev/null` part should suffice.

Comment: @DonHolgo thank you, I guess that was the answer, just needed the php file.php `>/dev/null` part.  In full:, `cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/detailed_payouts && for FILE in *; do dos2unix $FILE; done && php /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydeal-join-columns-2.php >/dev/null && cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/xero-bills && csvstack * > xero-bills-csvstacked.csv && cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/xero-invoices && csvstack * > xero-inv-csvstacked.csv`